# How to know about Idle connectins in DB2?

Tags: database, db2

I have huge Inactive sessions to in db2 and I want to know to which application / user these connections belongs to . Is there anyway ? I am not sure about this . Please help out in this issue .

Regards,

Raj

Answer (score 2):

From the DB2 Command Line, you can use [`LIST APPLICATIONS`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001958.html):

```
db2 list applications show detail
```

You have to have the proper privileges on the database instance (most commonly `SYSADM` or `SYSCTRL`).

Answer (score 0):

DB2 has useful FUNCTIONs that can be used to get snapshot information from the database. 
E.g. list applications that are connected to TEST and have been idle for 24 hours:

```
db2 "connect to TEST"
db2 "select execution_id, appl_id, appl_status, status_change_time from table(snap_get_appl_info('TEST')) snap where status_change_time < current timestamp - 24 hours"
```

See 
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0021987.html
for more details.

**EDIT**

Forgot to mention that you need to have UOW monitors on for getting "status change time" information.

For instance level:

```
db2 update dbm cfg using DFT_MON_UOW ON
```

For db level:

```
db2 update monitor switches using UOW ON
```

Comment: You can get snapshots with `db2 get snapshot` command. See `db2 ? get snapshot` for details.